# SOLID Principles : interfaces vs. abstract classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have a particular edge case where I'm not sure whether to use an interface or an abstract class. Initially my design used an abstract class where the methods were implemented as `protected internal abstract void`.

This was useful because I wanted the methods to be callable from within my assembly, but only available through inheritance outside of my assembly.

The problem I encountered was that not all derivatives of the abstract class needed to implement the functionality, so essentially I ended up with empty method bodies.

This is where I had the idea of using interfaces, which meant that I could implement required functionality via the interface, however this meant that the methods would need to be public, and as specified above, I only want the methods to be available through inheritance.

**Example using an abstract class:**

```
abstract class Dependency
{
    protected internal abstract void DoThis();
    protected internal abstract void DoThat();
}

sealed class DerivedDependency : Dependency
{
    protected override void DoThis()
    {
        // implementation...
    }

    protected override void DoThat()
    {
        // not required...
    }
}
```

**Example using interfaces:**

```
abstract class Dependency
{
    // whilst this is now empty, it is still required to provide a type hierarchy!
}

interface IDoThis
{
    void DoThis();
}

interface IDoThat
{
    void DoThat();
}

sealed class DerivedDependency : Dependency, IDoThis
{
    public virtual void DoThis()
    {
        // I only need this functionality. I don't need to DoThat();
    }
}
```

So I am wondering what is better really. Both offer features I want, but it seems that I can't have both.

Do I just put up with having empty method bodies that 3rd parties might implement, not realising they're not meant to be implemented, or, do I implement required functionality only, but risk exposing the functionality via instantiation?

Comment: "I have a particular edge case where I'm not sure whether to use an interface or an abstract class" IMO, use an interface. Always.

Comment: If in your inheritance chain there are methods without implementation (because you don't need them) then I will consider this as Interface Segregation Principle is broken

Comment: What exactly are you "risking" for making these methods public? Should they be internal implementation detail of your classes?

Comment: Why must it be either/or?  You can implement an interface, and have your abstract class derive from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mentioning solid, what you're missing is Interface Segregation Principle, you should use two interfaces, one for internal consumers (the methods marked as internal) and another for the external ones.

So I would not go for an abstract class nor for an inteface, but for two (or more) interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution which seems to work nicely, but I would like the communities opinion on whether this abides by or violates SOLID principles:

```
interface IDoThis
{
    void DoThis();
}

class Dependency : IDoThis
{
    protected internal virtual void DoThis()
    {
        // impl.
    }

    void IDoThis.DoThis()
    {
        this.DoThis();
    }
}

IDoThis idt = new Dependency();
idt.DoThis() // calls into the protected method.
```

This allows me to segregate functionality via interfaces (ISP), access it publicly within the assembly, and override it in external assemblies (OCP)

Comment: You're still publicly exposing "DoThis()". I don't see how this is better than implicitly implementing the interface.